# Highchart not displaying with svelte

Tags: javascript, highcharts, svelte

i'm using svelte to make graphic representation of some lists. The problem is that i have tried everything but it doesn't work (I opened the console and it shows me no errors, so i cant see where I have failed).
I have copied the code from the main page of Highcharts for the loadGraph(), the rest of the code is from the users community and it works fine...

```js
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import Highcharts from "highcharts";
    import Button from "sveltestrap/src/Button.svelte";
    

    export let params = {};
    //const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

    let apiData = [];
    let country = params.country;
    let pais = [];
    let year = [];
    let male = [];
    let female = [];
    let total = [];

    

    let male2015 = [];
    let male2016 = [];
    let male2017 = [];
    let male2018 = [];
    let male2019 = [];
    let male2020 = [];

    let female2015 = [];
    let female2016 = [];
    let female2017 = [];
    let female2018 = [];
    let female2019 = [];
    let female2020 = [];

    let total2015 = [];
    let total2016 = [];
    let total2017 = [];
    let total2018 = [];
    let total2019 = [];
    let total2020 = [];

    let sumaMale2015 = 0;
    let sumaMale2016 = 0;
    let sumaMale2017 = 0;
    let sumaMale2018 = 0;
    let sumaMale2019 = 0;
    let sumaMale2020 = 0;

    let sumaFemale2015 = 0;
    let sumaFemale2016 = 0;
    let sumaFemale2017 = 0;
    let sumaFemale2018 = 0;
    let sumaFemale2019 = 0;
    let sumaFemale2020 = 0;

    let sumaTotal2015 = 0;
    let sumaTotal2016 = 0;
    let sumaTotal2017 = 0;
    let sumaTotal2018 = 0;
    let sumaTotal2019 = 0;
    let sumaTotal2020 = 0;

    async function getData(){
        const res1 = await fetch('/api/v1/proportion-stats');
        if (res1.ok){
            const arrayData = await res1.json();
            apiData = arrayData;
            console.log("api data : " + apiData);
            //Ordenamos valores:
            apiData.sort(function (a, b) {
                var keyA = new Date(a.year),
                    keyB = new Date(b.year);
                // Compare the 2 dates
                if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
                if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
                return 0;
            });
            console.log(apiData.length);
            apiData.forEach((v) => {
                year.push(v.year);
                
                
            });
            console.log(year);

            for(let i = 0; i < year.length; i++){
                if(apiData[i].year == 2015){
                    male2015.push(apiData[i].male);
                    female2015.push(apiData[i].female);
                    total2015.push(apiData[i].total);
                }
                else if(apiData[i].year == 2016){
                    male2016.push(apiData[i].male);
                    female2016.push(apiData[i].female);
                    total2016.push(apiData[i].total);
                }
                else if(apiData[i].year == 2017){
                    male2017.push(apiData[i].male);
                    female2017.push(apiData[i].female);
                    total2017.push(apiData[i].total);
                }else if(apiData[i].year == 2018){
                    male2018.push(apiData[i].male);
                    female2018.push(apiData[i].female);
                    total2018.push(apiData[i].total);
                }else if(apiData[i].year == 2019){
                    male2019.push(apiData[i].male);
                    female2019.push(apiData[i].female);
                    total2019.push(apiData[i].total);
                }
                else if(apiData[i].year == 2020){
                    male2020.push(apiData[i].male);
                    female2020.push(apiData[i].female);
                    total2020.push(apiData[i].total);
                }
            }

            for(let i= 0; i< male2015; i++){
                sumaMale2015 = sumaMale2015 + male2015[i];
                sumaFemale2015 = sumaFemale2015 + female2015[i];
                sumaTotal2015 = sumaTotal2015 + total2015[i];
            }
            for(let i= 0; i< male2016; i++){
                sumaMale2016 = sumaMale2016 + male2016[i];
                sumaFemale2016 = sumaFemale2016 + female2016[i];
                sumaTotal2016 = sumaTotal2016 + total2016[i];
            }
            for(let i= 0; i< male2017; i++){
                sumaMale2017 = sumaMale2017 + male2017[i];
                sumaFemale2017 = sumaFemale2017 + female2017[i];
                sumaTotal2017 = sumaTotal2017 + total2017[i];
            }
            for(let i= 0; i< male2018; i++){
                sumaMale2018 = sumaMale2018 + male2018[i];
                sumaFemale2018 = sumaFemale2018 + female2018[i];
                sumaTotal2018 = sumaTotal2018 + total2018[i];
            }
            for(let i= 0; i< male2019; i++){
                sumaMale2019 = sumaMale2019 + male2019[i];
                sumaFemale2019 = sumaFemale2019 + female2019[i];
                sumaTotal2019 = sumaTotal2019 + total2019[i];
            }
            for(let i= 0; i< male2020; i++){
                sumaMale2020 = sumaMale2020 + male2020[i];
                sumaFemale2020 = sumaFemale2020 + female2020[i];
                sumaTotal2020 = sumaTotal2020 + total2020[i];
            }

        

        loadGraph();
    }else{
        window.alert("No hay datos cargados");
        console.log("INTERNAL FATAL ERROR");
        window.location.href ='/#/proportion-stats';
    }
}


    
    async function loadGraph(){

        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Proportion of '
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: '% of population'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Male',
                data: [sumaMale2015, sumaMale2016, sumaMale2017, sumaMale2018, sumaMale2019, sumaMale2020]
            }, {
                name: 'Female',
                data: [sumaFemale2015, sumaFemale2016, sumaFemale2017, sumaFemale2018, sumaFemale2019, sumaFemale2020]
            },{
                name: 'Total',
                data: [sumaTotal2015, sumaTotal2016, sumaTotal2017, sumaTotal2018, sumaTotal2019, sumaTotal2020]
            }]
        });
    }

 onMount(getData);
</script>


<svelte:head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"on:load={loadGraph}></script>

    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container"></div>
        <p class="highcharts-description">
            This chart shows how data labels can be added to the data series. This
            can increase readability and comprehension for small datasets.
        </p>
    </figure>

</svelte:head>

<main>
    <br />
    <h1 align="center">Pais al que buscar gráfica:</h1>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="text" bind:value={country} />
        <Button
            outline
            color="info"
            on:click={() => {
                window.location.href =  `/#/graphProportionSearch/${country}`;
                location.reload();

            }}
        >
            Buscar
        </Button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container" />
    </figure>
    <br />
    <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container" />
        <p class="highcharts-description">
            En esta gráfica se muestra para el pais seleccionado el avance de la
            tasa de empleo, educación o capacitación de los jóvenes.
        </p>
    </figure>
</main>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the charta configuration to a minimum? From what I can see you are trying to load the container in HTML with the chart three times maybe it is blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `figure` with an `id` of *container* in your `svelte:head` block. Highcharts is trying to render your graph there (in fact it is even managing to do so, if you would inspect the page).

I also see you have several elements with an `id` of *container*, id has to be **unique** to work correctly.